# Create a Power Table in Java

Tags: java, exponent

I need to make a powers table in Java. This would be stored. I've found no way to do this easily, as `Map` only has 2 entries. Is there an easy way to do this? What I need to do is have a table (not on GUI) such as the following:

```
Base         Power            BaseToPower
1            1                1
5            2                25
```

And so on. How would I do this?

Comment: Depends... what kind of lookups are you going to do on the table?

Comment: What do you mean by create? Do you need to the values to be kept in storage, or do you just want the values printed out?

Comment: @dnault I'm going to be looking up if one BaseToPower equals another, and if so reading the Base and Power. peeskillet In storage/variable

Comment: use a `Map<int,Map<int,int>` :) first map's key for base value,
second map's key for power and value for basetopower

Comment: You can use `Map<Integer, List<Integer>>`

Comment: @ismail you might want to make that an answer

Comment: Can you just use a 2D array?

Comment: @ismail How do I put integers into that second Map?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

use a `Map<int,Map<int,int>>` :) first map's key for base value, second map's key for power and value for basetopower

Edit

I thought `Map<Integer,Integer[][]>` is a better solution

for putting rows

```
Map<Integer,Integer[][]> mainMap = new HashMap<Integer,Integer[][]>();
Integer[][] row1 = new Integer[1][2];//first base and power
row1[0][0] = 1;
row1[0][1] = 1;
Integer[][] row2 = new Integer[1][2];//second base and power
row2[0][0] = 2;
row2[0][1] = 5;

mainMap.put(1,row1);
mainMap.put(25,row2);
```

For retreving the values

```
 for (Map.Entry<Integer, Integer[][]> entry : mainMap.entrySet()) {
        System.out.println("Base= " + entry.getKey() 
            + ", Power= " + entry.getValue()[0][0]
            + ", BaseToPower= " + entry.getValue()[0][1]);

}
//mainMap.get(25); will return base and power array
```

I didn't test it sorry for mistakes if there are

Comment: I tried this `lis.put((new Map().put(2,25)),5);` with `Map<Map<Integer,Integer>, Integer> lis = new HashMap<Map<Integer,Integer>, Integer>();`, but it says `The method put(Map<Integer,Integer>, Integer) in the type Map<Map<Integer,Integer>,Integer> is not applicable for the arguments (Object, int)`

Comment: you are using a Map as an object(instead of key) but it is an interface so it cannot be used as you used

Comment: I would want to search for the BaseToPower, though, so how could I do that? Also, it looks like for the int[] solution, I would have to manually define each row? Not just have a for loop?

Comment: This is giving `Syntax error on token "int", invalid Expression`, `int` of `int[1][2];`.

Comment: just copy and paste i tried and it's working now
the error was `int[1][2]` need to be like that `new int[1][2]`

Comment: yeah :) realy ah for me too. you're wellcome

Comment: Hey, I just realized something. My BaseToPower is a BigInteger, so it may excede the limit for an integer. How can I change this so that an Int[][] can somehow take a BigInteger?

Comment: are you kidding me :) really?

Comment: How can I select one value, and check if it is equal to any other?

Comment: I edited it, use mainMap.get(BaseToPower); to retrive base and power

Answer (score 1):

A common implementation of a Table structure in Java is to use a `List` of `Maps` so the Map key in each row is the column heading, like this:

```
List<Map<String,Integer>> table = new ArrayList<>();
Map<String,Integer> row1 = new HashMap<>();
row1.put("Base",1);
row1.put("Power",1);
row1.put("BaseToPower",1);
table.add(row1);
```

etc.

A better solution, however, may be to create a bean class to represent a table row.

```
public class TableRow {
   private int base;
   private int power;
   private int baseToPower;

   ... Getters and Setters ...
}
```

You could then store these TableRow objects in a `List<TableRow>` or perhaps `LinkedHashMap<Integer,TableRow>` depending on how you want to access them.

Answer (score 0):

If you want just want to find the value of a base to a power you can use `Math.pow(base, power)` and then cast it to an `int`; it is probably fast enough.  Alternatively, if you want to store the values compactly, you can use an `int[][3]`.

Answer (score 0):

I would either use `Map<int, Map<int, int>` or something like `Map<int, Vector<int>>` if you always have a fixed length number of powers, because with the nested maps, you'll have to manually input the powers ;)

Answer (score -1):

```
Power Table in Java
```

### Create a Power Table in Java

```
import java.util.*;    
class powerseries    
{    
    public static void main(String[] ar)    
    {    
    Scanner o=new Scanner(System.in);    
    int num,i,temp=1,temp2=1;    
    System.out.print("\nEnter Table number for powerseries:  ");    
    num=o.nextInt();    

    for(i=1;i<=10;i++)    
        {    
    System.out.println(num+" ^ "+i+" = "+(temp2*num));    
    temp2=temp2*num; /*multiply coming number*/
        }       
    }   
}
```

Comment: "... What I need to do is have a table **(not on GUI)** .."